# How to Clear Cookies in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In Our application while testing Manually we clear Cookies (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>),
How can I automate this step?

Note: We are using Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete cookies using cookiename and all cookies alltogether.

To delete a particular cookie , use this

```
driver.manage().deleteCookieNamed(cookiename);
```

Python version of this method is

```
driver.delete_cookie(cookiename)
```

To delete all cookies at once

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Python version for the same above is

```
driver.delete_all_cookies()
```

These are same for all browsers.

Comment: A small warning is that these look like non blocking methods - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504358/waiting-for-deleting-cookies-with-webdriver

Comment: Also, `deleteAllCookies` will only delete cookies under the domain of currently opened page.

Comment: @KenstonChoi Yes, right!! How to delete from other domains as well??

Comment: @Pranav-BitWiser, some sites suggest that the browser has to visit these domains individually and delete the cookies. The easiest is to just launch a new browser session.

Comment: @KenstonChoi Does this means that launching a new session will automatically deletes all cookies?

Comment: @Pranav-BitWiser, yes, it will as it is a new browser profile/session (with a different id).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium methods to clear the cookies.Here is the example

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Comment: Is this Same for all Browsers?

Comment: yup, same for all for browsers